# Dojo Restful server access

Tags: rest, dojo

How to implement restful access from Dojo client to java server running in tomcat?
I need to make restful request to server and get data (json or xml format) and update the grid. How to do it?

I read the following posts, but i couldn't understand anything.
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/06/13/restful-json-dojo-data/
http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2008/11/21/effective-use-of-jsonreststore-referencing-lazy-loading-and-more/

Can anyone give me complete source code and the explanation ?

Since I am new to Dojo I feel hard to do this. I don't want web services to be included.

Answer (score 1):

For the REST part, you can use the Wizard of Netbeans (the tutorial is on Glassfish, but I don't see any reason why this should not work on Tomcat as well). See here the tutorial:
http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/websvc/rest.html .
For the dojo part, I have posted a complete example (which integrates perfectly with the REST implementation provided by Netbeans) here:
[Dojo grid nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6954704/dojo-grid-nested-json)

EDITED

In the Netbeans' tutorial there is a link for Tomcat users.